# Why must I specify the Global context for a symbol in a private package?

Tags: function-construction, packages, contexts

I have written two versions of the function below in a package. When I load the package and call the function, Why does the first version where the variable s has no explicit Context return the long variable name? Or why do I have to put the variable in the Global context to return the short name? While every other function component is automatically assigned to the package context. Is there something weird happening with the Block function?

```
x={{k1p -> 6.680629079305845`, k1m -> 9.100970498785017`, 
    k2p -> 5.9669213788246225`, state -> 1.`}, {k1p -> 6.680629079305845`, 
    k1m -> 9.100970498785017`, k2p -> 5.9669213788246225`, state -> 0.`}}
threadParameters[epsilon_/;epsilon==1,k_,params_,
signal_:signal,numberOfStrains_:numberOfStrains]:=
  Block[{variateList,s,i,j},
   variateList = params;
    (*Prepare each jth simulation parameter list by
     adding the appropriate signal strength*)
   mutantParameters =
    Table[
     Join[{s->j},variateList[[i]]],
     {j,signal},
     {i,1,numberOfStrains}
    ]
 ];
 threadParameters[1, 1, x,{1,3,5},2]
({SimulatorV2Debug`Private`s->1,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p>5.96692,state->1.}
 {SimulatorV2Debug`Private`s->1,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p->5.96692,state->0.}
 {SimulatorV2Debug`Private`s->3,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p->5.96692,state->1.}
 {SimulatorV2Debug`Private`s->3,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p->5.96692,state->0.}
 {SimulatorV2Debug`Private`s->5,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p->5.96692,state->1.}
 {s->5,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p->5.96692,state->0.})

threadParameters[epsilon_/;epsilon==1,k_,params_,
signal_:signal,numberOfStrains_:numberOfStrains]:=
  Block[{variateList,s,i,j},
   variateList = params;
    (*Prepare each jth simulation parameter list by
     adding the appropriate signal strength*)
   mutantParameters =
    Table[
     Join[{Global`s->j},variateList[[i]]],
     {j,signal},
     {i,1,numberOfStrains}
    ]
 ];
 threadParameters1[1, 1, x,{1,3,5},2]
({s->1,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p>5.96692,state->1.}
 {s->1,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p->5.96692,state->0.}
 {s->3,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p->5.96692,state->1.}
 {s->3,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p->5.96692,state->0.}
 {s->5,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p->5.96692,state->1.}
 {s->5,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p->5.96692,state->0.})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every symbol always has a context. Most of the time we are in the `Global` context.

```
$Context
(* "Global`" *)
```

Normally we don't have to specify a variable as

```
Global`s
```

Simply writing `s` is sufficient provided we are in the `Global` context.

Inside your package the symbols and functions are defined in the

```
SimulatorV2Debug`Private
```

context. In the function `threadParameters` inside the `Block` the variable `s` is from that context.

That is why you get the two different results.

**One**

`s` is in the

```
SimulatorV2Debug`Private
```

context and you get for example:

```
{SimulatorV2Debug`Private`s->1,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p>5.96692,state->1.}
```

**Two**

In your function you explcity use:

```
Join[{Global`s->j},variateList[[i]]],
```

so `s` is in the `Global` context and you get:

```
{s->1,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p>5.96692,state->1.}
```

Note that this is the same as:

```
{Global`s->1,k1p->6.68063,k1m->9.10097,k2p>5.96692,state->1.}
```

Simply because `$Context` is `Global`, the long name is not written.

**PS**

I didn't want to introduce a diversion but in your second definition you are missing a comma here:

```
threadParameters[epsilon_/;epsilon==1,k_,params_
```

I suspect that is simply a copy and paste error.

Comment: Ah yes, that is a typo. Now fixed.